# Ubuntu MAAS 14.04 Cant add nodes

Tags: 14.04, maas, dhcp, pxe

```
root@spsandboxbl02:/var/log/maas# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

Following this guide:

http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html

```
root@spsandboxbl02:/var/log/maas# apt-get install maas maas-cluster-controller maas-dhcp maas-dns
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
maas is already the newest version.
maas-cluster-controller is already the newest version.
maas-cluster-controller set to manually installed.
maas-dhcp is already the newest version.
maas-dns is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

I have a MAAS server up and running with 3 networks;

```
MGMT - x.x.x.0/26 DNS and DHCP Managed PUBLIC - y.y.y.0/26 Unmanaged DATA - z.z.z.0/26 Unmanaged
```

I have the MAAS Cluster manager node up and running, PXE boot images downloaded, but am unable to join nodes to it. My additional nodes are using eth0 and should be receiving DHCP from MAAS but are not. Even manually restarting the dhcp server in the MAAS node has no effect.
As a result PXE is also not usable.

```
Symptoms:

Manually adding a node:

no communication

PXE booting a node on the MAAS managed net:

No DHCP address received (apt-get install maas-dhcp maas-dns completed, dpkg-reconfigure maas-dhcp and MAAS performed as well)
```

Booting from the install disk as MAAS install:

No DHCP, manual networking config on the subnet completed with a sigterm, node doesnt come back up or provide a status message of any type, and has nothing on it after 6 hours.

I have found no way to add nodes to MAAS using Ubuntu 14.04 (no vlans) so far.

Answer (score 1):

After setting the private subnets that I wanted to allow access to the Squid proxy in `/etc/squid=deb-proxy/allowed-networks-src.acl` like

```
# private networks
192.168.1.0/24
```

I still had this issue;

I added the following to my `/etc/squid\-deb-proxy/squid-deb-proxy.conf`:

```
cache_peer proxy.domain.com parent 8080 0 no-query default login=anonymous:password
```

This tells Squid to funnel requests directly to the proxy transparently.  Nodes are installing fine now.